# RVM switching Rails Versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

The situation is that my default gemset on my computer points to `rails 5.0.0`.  However: I have an app that uses a really old rails version. Lets say for this example the app uses: `rails 2.1.1`.

Does my machine automatically switch to `rails 2.1.1` when `cd'ed` into this app because `rails 2.1.1` is specified in the `Gemfile`?  Or: do I need to ***explicitly*** create a gemset in order for my app and my machine to do things the "rails 2.1.1 way" (as opposed to doing stuff the "rails 5.0.0 way which is the rails version in my default gemset)?

My concern is that perhaps if my machine thinks I am using `rails 5.0.0` instead of `rails 2.1.1` while developing inside the app: then rails commands such as generators might create files and do stuff "the rails 5.0.0 way" as opposed to the "rails 2.1.1" way.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Here is what I would do in order to "explicitly" state via a Gemset that this app uses `rails 2.1.1`

**Example:**

I create a gemset that is to be specified for any app that uses `rails 2.1.1`

```
rvm gemset create rails_2_1_1
```

I specify the ruby version to use on this gemset

```
rvm use 2.2.1@rails_2_1_1
```

I then install that old version of rails onto this gemset:

```
gem install rails --version=2.1.1
```

Now this gemset uses `rails 2.1.1`.

Now at the root of my app I specify a `.ruby-gemset` file that tells rails: "Make sure you are doing stuff the `rails 2.1.1` way and not the `rails 5.0.0` way:

```
#.ruby-gemset
rails_2_1_1
```

I want to be sure that if another rails version is specified in an app's Gemfile than is in my default gemset: then developing within that app will do everything within the context of the rails version specified in the Gemfile as opposed to the rails version in the default gemset.

Comment: Are you using Bundler? If not, can you add Bundler to the project? That would solve this problem tidily.

Comment: @Jordan I am using Bundler. Do I need to be sure I run `bundle` every time I `cd` into this app?  Or: just the first time in order to generate the `Gemfile.lock` and then I no longer need to do it?

Comment: You only have to run `bundle` once, unless you switch to a different Ruby version (and even then, if you switch *back*, you don't have to run `bundle` again). I don't think you need to bother with gemsets if you're using Bundler. As long as you use `bundle exec`, it will use the version of Rails installed by Bundler (i.e. the one in your Gemfile). Here's some more information on using Bundler with RVM: https://rvm.io/integration/bundler

Comment: P.S. I don't know if Rails 2.1 has this command, but the [Rails 2.3 command line guide mentions `./script/about`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/command_line.html), which will print, among other things, the current Ruby and Rails versions. Try `bundle exec ./script/about` and see what happens.

Comment: if you have .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset set up correctly simply cd'ing into the project directory will put those things in play...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a problem with RVM and Rails. Using the Gemfile is the best way to do this, IMHO! In your Gemfile, you can specify which ruby and which gemset within that ruby to use.

### Set Default Ruby/Gemset --for system

First, lets establish that **default** ruby for the system on `5.0.0`. This will allow any new/existing Rails projects to default to this ruby version (except for those projects that override with the Gemfile):

```
rvm use --default 5.0.0
```

..and of course, if you want it fixed to a specified gemset:

```
rvm use --default 5.0.0@my_default_gemset
```

### Set Default Ruby/Gemset --for Rails specific App on Gemfile

#### Example 1

If you want to setup your rails app to utilize the RVM gemset `2.2.1@rails_2_1_1`, similar to the RVM command below...

```
rvm use 2.2.1@rails_2_1_1
```

In your Gemfile, specify right below the `source` line the following two commented lines:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
#ruby=2.2.1
#ruby-gemset=rails_2_1_1
```

Now, when you `cd` into your rails' app directory, you should receive the following message, or similiar:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does 
that too, you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore 
/my/rails/app/path/Gemfile'.

To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore
allGemfiles'.
```

You can double check your results:

```
rvm list gemsets

   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1@global [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.2.1@rails_2_1_1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-5.0.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-5.0.0@global [ x86_64 ]
```

#### Example 2

Another example using `ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0.0`, example RVM command...

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0.0
```

In your Gemfile, specify:

```
#ruby=2.0.0-p247
#ruby-gemset=rails-4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create rvmrc file into your project directory then it will switch rvm automatically

Please follow the process to create rvmrc file.

Go to project directory

```
 rvm use 2.2.1@rails_2_1_1

 rvm --rvmrc --create 2.2.1@rails_2_1_1
```

I think it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.ruby-version` file in your project's folder and RVM will automatically switch to the correct Ruby. Something like this:

```
$ echo '2.1.1' > .ruby-version
```

You just need to make sure you have that version installed, eg.:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.1.1
```

Comment: My question above might not be clear.  I am not concerned with the ruby version.  I am concerned about the rails version.

Comment: rails gem version should be called out in Gemfile. If it is then your rvm set up with the .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files set up correctly will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend against using `.ruby-gemset` file, because `Gemfile` already has everything you'll need. `.ruby-version` is obsolete too, because Ruby version can be specified inside `Gemfile` as well:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7'
...
```

Now about Rails versions. As long as you run commands with `bundle exec`, these commands' versions will be exactly as stated in `Gemfile`.

There are also `binstubs` scripts inside projects `bin/` folder. They're the most preferable way to run commands, because they're usually tweaked for project needs (for example running `spring` along with your command) and they ultimately run `bundle exec` anyways.

So the proper way to do things, is to run `./bin/rails`, which can be tedious. That's why I recommend using helpers. For example, [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) project has out-of-the-box `rails` plugin. First  few lines (read below for explanation):

```
function _rails_command () {
  if [ -e "bin/rails" ]; then
    bin/rails $@
  elif [ -e "script/rails" ]; then
    ruby script/rails $@
  elif [ -e "script/server" ]; then
    ruby script/$@
  else
    command rails $@
  fi
}

function _rake_command () {
  if [ -e "bin/rake" ]; then
    bin/rake $@
  elif type bundle &> /dev/null && [ -e "Gemfile" ]; then
    bundle exec rake $@
  else
    command rake $@
  fi
}

alias rails='_rails_command'
compdef _rails_command=rails

alias rake='_rake_command'
compdef _rake_command=rake
```

When you run `rails`, this script checks if `bin/rails` exists (Rails 5 and 4 default) and runs it instead. If not, script checks for `script/rails` (Rails 3 default) and `script/server` (Rails 2 default). So basically you have all versions covered. Same is for `rake`.

With this plugin you never need to worry about extra commands. Always simply run `rails`. You just install it once and forget about it.